# What is this CASE statement doing exactly with the NVL function?

Tags: oracle

```
case when nvl(Q_IND, 0) = 1 then 1 else 0 end Q_IND
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what is happening in the above statement. Could someone explain?

Comment: You can just replace it with `case when Q_IND = 1 then 1 else 0 end Q_IND` the NVL isn't doing anything for you here except hampering readability. If `Q_IND` is NULL then that won't be treated as equal to 1 anyway. No need to replace it with 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm):

> NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query. If expr1 is null, then NVL returns expr2. If expr1 is not null, then NVL returns expr1.

So for your specific example, if `Q_IND` is `NULL` then 0 is returned to the `CASE` statement. For such scenarios your `CASE` statement becomes this:

```
CASE WHEN 0 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Q_IND
```

We all know that 0 is not equal to 1 and thus 0 is returned as `Q_IND`.